# Storing and accessing array from mongodb-express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am storing an array from jade into mongodb.

Eg. input(name='name[]',type='text')->Firstname,input(name='name[]',type='text')->lastname (just eg). 
So i have a name array. I have stored into mongodb using the schema
('name':Array) and the values get stored as 'name':[['firsname','lastname']].

But when accessing back in jade, name[0] contains both firstname and last name values as a singe string.

name[0] outputs "firstname,lastname".  I want it as the original array, like name[0]='firstname' and name[1]='lastname'.Please help me out. Trying for more than a week!

Answer (score 0):

You have an `Array` of an `Array`:

```
'name':[['firsname','lastname']]
```

So instead of `name`, `name[0]` is the "*original `Array`*" and to access each value from it you need to use:

```
name[0][0] // first name
name[0][1] // last name
```

---

Otherwise, to have `name` be a single `Array`, that depends on how you're currently modifying the model. But, simply setting it to the form data should be sufficient:

```
yourModel.name = req.body.name;
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
name[0] // first name
name[1] // last name
```

Comment: Found it.. Instead of using name[] in html form, I tried with just name='name' for both the input types. and it worked!